# tkinter Factorial import

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to create a basic Calculator using tkinter. I'd like to add the factorial function to my calculator, but I don't know how. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from math import *
from math import factorial as fact

class Aplication(Frame):
def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
    self.createWidgets()

def replaceText(self, text):
    self.display.delete(0, END)
    self.display.insert(0, text)

def clcExp(self):
    self.expression = self.display.get()
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("×", "*")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("÷", "/")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("%", "/ 100")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("!", "fact")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("mod", "%")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("√", "** 0.5")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("²", "** 2")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace("³", "** 3")
    self.expression = self.expression.replace(",", ".")

    try:
        self.result = eval(self.expression)
        self.replaceText(self.result)
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Input", "ERROR")

def appendToDisplay(self, text):
            self.entryText = self.display.get()
            self.textLength = len(self.entryText)

            if self.entryText == "0":
                self.replaceText(text)

            else:
                self.display.insert(self.textLength, text)

def clearText(self):
    self.replaceText("0")


def createWidgets(self):
    self.display = Entry(self, font = ("Times", 16), borderwidth = 1, relief = RAISED, justify = RIGHT)
    self.display.insert(0, "0")
    self.display.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5)

    self.pctBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "%", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("%"))
    self.pctBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.rootBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "√", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("√"))
    self.rootBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.sqrBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "x²", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("²"))
    self.sqrBtn.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.cubeBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "x³", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("³"))
    self.cubeBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.modBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "mod", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay(" mod "))
    self.modBtn.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.clearBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "CLEAR", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.clearText())
    self.clearBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 3, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.sevenBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "7", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("7"))
    self.sevenBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.fourBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "4", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("4"))
    self.fourBtn.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.oneBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "1", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("1"))
    self.oneBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.fact = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "n!", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("!"))
    self.fact.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.eightBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "8", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("8"))
    self.eightBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.fiveBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "5", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("5"))
    self.fiveBtn.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.twoBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "2", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("2"))
    self.twoBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.zeroBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "0", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("0"))
    self.zeroBtn.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.nineBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "9", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("9"))
    self.nineBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.sixBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "6", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("6"))
    self.sixBtn.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.threeBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "3", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("3"))
    self.threeBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.commaBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = ",", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay(","))
    self.commaBtn.grid(row = 5, column = 3, sticky ='NWNESWSE')


    self.divisionBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "÷", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("÷"))
    self.divisionBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.timesBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "×", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("×"))
    self.timesBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 4, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.minusBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "-", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("-"))
    self.minusBtn.grid(row = 3, column = 4, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.plusBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "+", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.appendToDisplay("+"))
    self.plusBtn.grid(row = 4, column = 4, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

    self.equalBtn = Button(self, font = ("Times", 12), text = "=", borderwidth = 1, command = lambda: self.clcExp())
    self.equalBtn.grid(row = 5, column = 4, sticky ='NWNESWSE')

calculator = Tk()
calculator.title("Calculator")
calculator.resizable(0,0)
app = Aplication(calculator).grid()
calculator.mainloop()
```

I tried to import factorial as fact and replace by using

```
self.expression = self.expression.replace("!", "fact")
```

but when I try to put 5! I get the 'Invalid Input' error I wrote in the messagebox. I tested the same thing importing the square root and using sqrt instead of ** 0.5. How can I add the factorial? I apologize for bad formatting, this is my first post here.

Comment: If your question is about replacing a string in an expression, you don't need all of that tkinter code. You just need to create a small program that has the same problem. See [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You could "monkey-patch" the float class to have a `factorial()` method, and then `5!` would become `5.factorial()`.

Comment: Unlike in Ruby, you can't monkey-patch built-in classes without a really nasty, crash-prone dive past protection layers intended to keep you out. It's not as simple as `float.factorial = whatever`, and it's not a thing to encourage.